# How to automatically redirect to Stripe checkout on page load without a button

Tags: javascript

So basically, I want to add this script to a page where it will automatically redirect to the checkout, without showing a checkout button and without having to click on any button.

How do I do this?

I want to do this because I'm using an online website builder where this code doesn't work. This is a direct and easy workaround where I would simply link the checkout button within the website builder to an external page with this code. That would work for me.

```
<!-- Load Stripe.js on your website. -->
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>

<!-- Create a button that your customers click to complete their purchase. Customize the styling to suit your branding. -->
<button
  style="background-color:#6772E5;color:#FFF;padding:8px 12px;border:0;border-radius:4px;font-size:1em"
  id="ButtonPlan"
  role="link"
>
  Checkout
</button>

<div id="error-message"></div>

<script>
  var stripe = Stripe('APIkey');

  var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('ButtonPlan');
  checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
    // them to Checkout.
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      items: [{plan: 'ButtonPlan', quantity: 1}],

      // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
      // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
      // a successful payment.
      // Instead use one of the strategies described in
      // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment
      successUrl: 'https://www.url.com/success',
      cancelUrl: 'https://www.url.com/cancel',
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
        // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
        var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
        displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I expect this script to automatically redirect to checkout once external page is loaded, without the need for a button to trigger checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the same code but don't attach it to `checkoutButton.addEventListener`:

```
<!-- Load Stripe.js on your website. -->
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>

<div id="error-message"></div>

<script>
var stripe = Stripe('APIkey');

// redirect them to Checkout.
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  items: [{plan: 'ButtonPlan', quantity: 1}],

  // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
  // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
  // a successful payment.
  // Instead use one of the strategies described in
  // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment
  successUrl: 'https://www.url.com/success',
  cancelUrl: 'https://www.url.com/cancel',
})
.then(function (result) {
  if (result.error) {
    // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
    // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
    var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
    displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Yes. Worked beautifully. Thanks so much!